# can't create triggers with two table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a Transaction table and Student table, and I will make a trigger that is used for the Transaction table, the question is why I cannot retrieve data from the student table while the transaction table and student table have relations

Comment: _The trouble with TRIGGLES_ :)

Comment: One should never interrupt 2 tables having relations :) :)

Comment: But seriously now Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)